# HTML form authentication for Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I want to secure a part of my site served by Apache with an HTML form. Apache 2.3 has a module name [mod_auth_form](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_auth_form.html) for this purpose. How do I do it on Apache 2.0?

I do not want to use HTTP authentication.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking how to use an Apache 2.3 module on Apache 2.0 (an older version)? That can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Apache, you need to use basic/digest HTTP authentication or some kind of content management system with it's own auth system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for solution to this problem too.

After searching for some time, I found the solution called mod_auth_cookie_mysql

With the module, you authenticate a user with MySQL, then set the cookie in the browser.

When accessing a secured site, the module will verify the cookie with information in MySQL, and will allow authenticated user in.

More info at http://home.digithi.de/digithi/dev/mod_auth_cookie_mysql/

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your server to Apache 2.3/2.4. There's a reason why new versions come out: new features